# Добавление динамических полей в форму в Yii

Tags: php, yii, javascript

Есть форма, в которую админ может добавить еще поля (неограниченное кол-во).
хочу реализовать [вот такую технологическую линию](http://www.haas.com/ru/konechnye-produkty-i-tekhnologija-proizvodstva/vafelnyebrprodukty-19/ploskie-vafelnye-batonchiki-56/)
но не знаю как правильно это сделать, пока получается выводить инфу из базы, но совсем не понятно как ее туда забивать

на данный момент я создал модель(ConstructTehLine, ConstructTehLineAttributes) и контроллер (ConstructTehLineController)

ConstructTehLine

```
    public function relations()
{
    return array(
    'all_attribute_values' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ConstructTehLineAttributes', 'tehLine_id',
        'order'=>'tehLine_id ASC',
        'with'=>'tehLine_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

ConstructTehLineAttributes

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
        'tehLine_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ConstructTehLine', 'id'),
  );
}
```

[image: форма для наглядности]

Answer (score 1):

В `Yii` при использовании `ActiveRecord` есть методы `beforeSave` и `beforeValidate` (ну или `afterSave` и `afterValidate`, от кода вашего зависит), в одном из них вы можете отправлять данные в `ConstructTehLineAttributes`.

Также можно в контроллере после сохранения данных о тех. линии добавлять данные в `ConstructTehLineAttributes`, а во `view` просто выводить их в той же форме, но для каждого свои `input`'ы.

Или делать это с использованием `ajax`.

Или можете под себя стилизовать [`EditableGrid`](http://ybe.demopage.ru/).

Подходов в общем много.